# Making a list of objects filled with SOAP API data results in "Index out of range" exception

Tags: c#, soap

I use an e-commerce SOAP API, forgive me if it's too confusing to answer. I just want to know if I'm just making a stupid mistake before I write a ticket to API maintainers.

```
public void WriteXML()
        {
            var results = GetProductsFromApi().results.ToList();
            using (var file = File.Create(@"products.xml"))
            {
                var list = new List<Product>();
                var writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    var newProduct = new Product
                    {
                        Id = result.productId,
                        Index = result.productDisplayedCode,
                        Stock = result.productStocksData.productStocksQuantities[0].productSizesData[0].productSizeQuantity,
                        IsIgnored = false,
                        IsInDelivery = false
                    };
                    list.Add(newProduct);
                }
                writer.Serialize(file, list);
            }
        }
```

I made a request to the API and I want to store it in a list, so each result gets serialized into an XML later. The code above works if I set `Stock` to something like `Stock = 1,` - however if left as it is, the program quits with `Unhandled exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

What's weird though is that if I do something similar to the following before building the `Product` object:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.productStocksData.productStocksQuantities[0].productSizesData[0].productSizeQuantity);
```

...I am met with a correct API response.

I have no clue what's going on. I tried checking if the result is `null` before constructing `Product`, but it didn't help. The whole exception is so confusing to me I don't really know where to start looking.

**Edit**: Using Fildor's proposed code, I wrote this:

```
    float? lol = result.productStocksData.productStocksQuantities.FirstOrDefault().productSizesData.FirstOrDefault()?.productSizeQuantity ?? null; //doesn't actually change anything if it's null or 0
    if (lol.GetValueOrDefault() == 0) {
        lol = 1;
    };

    var newProduct = new Product
    {
        Id = result.productId,
        Index = result.productDisplayedCode,
        Stock = (float)lol,
        IsIgnored = false,
        IsInDelivery = false
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Processed product has a stock of " + lol);
    list.Add(newProduct);
```

It now results in `System.NullReferenceException`. It responds with actual stock size, and said error appears after.

Comment: I would guess that there is (at least) one `result` where one of `productStocksQuantities` or `productSizesData` is empty (but not null). Maybe try `result.productStocksData.productStocksQuantities.FirstOrDefault()?.productSizesData.FirstOrDefault()?.productSizeQuantity ?? 0`.

Comment: @Fildor well, that seems obvious, yet I didn't try it - I'll make a check for it in a moment

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for a sample code. Your line results in a `System.ArgumentNullException`

Comment: That hints to that here is even a null somewhere. I guess you'll have to bite the sour apple and check each level for null or empty.

Comment: @Fildor I updated my code - now it says `System.NullReferenceException` - this is so arcane.

Comment: `float? lol = result.productStocksData.productStocksQuantities.FirstOrDefault().productS` insert another `?` behind that FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @Fildor Thanks a lot for your help, you guided me to the core of the problem: the error is produced entirely because of how our e-shop is being led - sorry for the hassle.